# Postgres equivalent to Oracle's "DIRECTORY" objects

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is it possible to create ["DIRECTORY"](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_5008.htm#SQLRF01207) object in Postgres?

If not can some help me with a solution how implement it on PostgreSQL.

Comment: If you mean equivalent for `create directory` as it exists in Oracle to point at directory where external table data are located, it does not exist in PostgreSQL. It uses bytea type - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-binary.html

Comment: Please explain the actual problem you are trying to solve with that.

Comment: thanks for your answer..

Comment: in oracle i was using 'create directory' as you said to point at an external directory so i could acess to it and write in with UTL_FILE..
i want to do the same in postgreSQL

'create or replace directory SRC_DIR
  as '&1';
  
GRANT READ, WRITE ON DIRECTORY SRC_DIR to &2._&3.;'

Comment: @Kamfasage I had the same issue ...How can we implement this in postgres like in oracle. To create the specified directory structure in windows environment. Have you resolved this ...Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Not the best option, but you could use:

```
COPY (select 1) TO PROGRAM 'mkdir --mode=777 -p /path/to/your/directory/'
```

Note that only the last part of directory get the permissions set in mode.

Answer (score 2):

There is no equivalent concept to an "Oracle directory" in Postgres.

The alternatives depend on *why* the "Oracle directory" is needed.

If the directory is needed to read and write files on the database server, then this can be done through [Generic File Access Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-GENFILE). Access to those functions is restricted to superusers (details in the linked section of the manual). If regular users should be able to use them, the best thing would be to create wrapper functions and then grant execute on those functions to the users in question.

For security reasons, only directories inside the [database cluster](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/storage-file-layout.html) can be accessed.

But it's possible to create symlinks inside the data directory that point to directories outside the data directory. Access privileges on those directories need to be properly setup for the postgres operating system user (the one under which the postgres process is started)

If the directory is needed to access e.g. CSV files through Oracle's external tables, then there is no need for a "directory". The [file FDW](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/file-fdw.html) foreign data wrapper, can access files outside the data directory (provided access privileges have been setup correctly on the file system level).

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't even make sense really. PostgreSQL is a *database management system*. It doesn't have files and directories.

The closest parallel I can think of is schemas - see `CREATE SCHEMA`.

Now, if you want to use `COPY` to write output to the server's disk and want to create a directory to put that output in... then no, there's nothing like that. But you can use PL/Perlu or PL/Pythonu to do it easily enough.

Comment: thanks @CraigRinger
can you please give me and example using PL/Perlu or PL/python of doing it?
i need to create into a folder a txt file, copy another existing  txt file into the one i created earlier and add some text into it

Comment: Not really, but you might want to start with the pl/python manual

Comment: I think the question is about the postgresql variant of Oracle `CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY .. AS` statement. Isn't it?

Comment: @AmithChinthaka If Oracle has such a statement then yeah, probably. Poster didn't say anything about Oracle and I have no idea what they're on about...