# Create a specified directory path in windows using PostgreSQL script

Tags: sql, postgresql

I had a requirement of creating a directory path in windows with full permissions using SQL script.

When I run the SQL script over the PostgreSQL database  it should create the directory path in windows environment.

```
The directory path should be like C:\test\script\run\result.
```

I tried to create directory path using CREATE DIRECTORY nothing worked out for me.

Comment: What is the exact command you tried to run? What error/unexpected result did you get? Could you clarify what you mean by "full permissions"?

Comment: @costaparas I tried to run this  "CREATE DIRECTORY C:\txt\aa\aaprd\database\data;" and i got the following error

Comment: @costaparas I got this error org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DIRECTORY"....My idea is to have a .sql file and when running that sql script over postgres db it should create the directory path specified in .sql script in windows environment.

Comment: CREATE DIRECTORY doesn't exist in Postgres. That is an Oracle keyword ... and that won't create a directory, it creates an alias for it.

Comment: I'm confused about your question. What is the purpose of this test directory you're creating? Also, you are using PostgreSQL, correct? Yet I see the question tagged with both PostgreSQL and Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I need this directory path to be created and  i need to store all my database .sql scripts in "results" directory. You said that CRETE DIRECTORY belongs to ORACLE right?. How can we do that in postgres to create a directory path .

Comment: In that case, I think you want this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608315/postgres-equivalent-to-oracles-directory-objects

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres equivalent to Oracle's "DIRECTORY" objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41608315/postgres-equivalent-to-oracles-directory-objects)

Comment: There is no such thing as "creating a directory in Postgres". If you want to create a directory to store SQL scripts (which are essentially text files) do that in Windows (e.g. `mkdir C:\test\script\run\result` in the command line).

Comment: @DaleK that did'nt help me

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just didn't want to do manual. I wanted it to execute automatically when the script got executed and creating directory path for me.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A SQL script must be stored in some directory to begin with, so how can you expect a script to create the directory in which it should be stored?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had a postgres database in remote machine. I just executing  all my sql scripts from another machine on that remote database. The idea was to create a directory path in the machine where db was installed and store all the db related config files their. Instead of creating directory path manually i am trying to do it with a sql script.

Comment: You can not create a directory in the file system on a remote server through SQL (not even Oracle's CREATE DIRECTORY would do that)

Comment: you can use the following command it worked for me                                                                           
     COPY (select 1) TO PROGRAM 'mkdir C:\tst\run\result' ;